# Resize the image to fit the background

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have used this method to resize the image

```
extension UIColor {
    static func imageWithBackgroundColor(image: UIImage, bgColor: UIColor) -> UIColor {
        let size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()


        let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, bgColor.CGColor)
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextDrawPath(context, .Fill)

        CGContextDrawImage(context, rectangle, image.CGImage)

        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return UIColor(patternImage: img)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
     let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

     // do some action
     // 
     if let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "myImage") { 
         delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.imageWithBackgroundColor(image: buttonImage, bgColor: UIColor.blueColor()) 
     }
     return [delete]
}
```

However, the image is upside down for this method. Any thoughts? Could anyone help to revise it or suggest any other method to resize the image so that it can totally fit to background.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
    withMaxDimension:(CGFloat)maxDimension
{
if (fmax(image.size.width, image.size.height) <= maxDimension) {
    return image;
}

CGFloat aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height;
CGSize newSize;

if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(maxDimension, maxDimension / aspect);
} else {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(maxDimension * aspect, maxDimension);
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,NO,0);
CGRect newImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height);
[image drawInRect:newImageRect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}

   /////// OR ////

- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage*)originalImage scaledToSize:(CGSize)size
 {
   //avoid redundant drawing
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(originalImage.size, size))
{
    return originalImage;
}

//create drawing context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);

//draw
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];

//capture resultant image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//return image
return image;
 }
```